# Where can I download the Shake gesture library for Windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, shake, app-hub

I have recently starting coding for windows phone 7, and have spent some time going round in circles trying to find the shake gesture library. Every link I follow tells me to go to the AppHub but when I follow it I get redirected to the main page asking me am I developing for windows phone or xbox.

I would be extremely grateful if anyone has the link to download the zip containing the dll and the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can sometimes find the content if you prepend "xbox." to the beginning an old creators club link ... but it does not work for every resource.

Try this link for now: http://xbox.create.msdn.com/downloads/?id=714

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite an old thread, but since it's the first result from search engines when you look for the Shake Gesture Library the actual answer may be useful.

You can download the library [from the Microsoft website](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=219094). Be aware that you must open this project in Visual Studio and compile it.

Don't trust compiled DLLs you find over the Internet - they may be modified version of the original library. Here you have the original Shake Gesture Library licensed in MS-PL, so you can use it your commercial project. You have also the source code of the library, so you can see how it works and eventually modify it according to your necessity.

The original blog post with the tutorial and explanation of how this library works is [here](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/02/22/windows-phone-shake-gestures-library.aspx).